# "The operation could not be completed. A retry should be performed" when trying to download platform-specific Binaries for Hyperledger sample

Tags: curl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Environment:

curl version: `curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL`

docker version:  `Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962`

operating system: `Windows 10 - command prompt`

I was trying to follow the steps to download and setup Hyperledger Fabric Samples by following the tutorial at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html

At the step "Download Platform-specific Binaries", I execute the following command:

`curl -sSL https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0 1.1.0 0.4.6`

And this is what I get:

```
C:\Users\177072\fabric\fabric-samples>curl -sSL https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0 1.1.0 0.4.6
The operation could not be completed. A retry should be performed.
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8661)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably be looking through the [1.4 docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html).

Second, those contain a similar set of steps, but the bootstrap link should be to the [raw version of the file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh).

If there's still a problem, I'll hope it's different, otherwise I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: I used the raw version URL and still getting the same result: C:\Users\177072\fabric-sample\fabric-samples>curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s
The operation could not be completed. A retry should be performed.
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8362)